# Replacing outliers with NaN in pandas dataframe after applying a .groupby() arguement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, outliers, pandas-groupby

I would like to remove outliers from a pandas dataframe using the standard deviation for a column variable after applying a groupby function.

Here is my data frame:

```
            ARI      Flesch    Kincaid             Speaker     Score
0     -2.090000  121.220000  -3.400000                 NaN       NaN   
1      8.276460   64.478573   9.034156      William Dudley  1.670275   
2     19.570911   27.362067  17.253580        Janet Yellen -0.604757   
3     -2.090000  121.220000  -3.400000                 NaN       NaN   
4     -2.090000  121.220000  -3.400000                 NaN       NaN   
5     20.643483   17.069411  18.394178       Lael Brainard  0.215396   
6     -2.090000  121.220000  -3.400000                 NaN       NaN   
7     -2.090000  121.220000  -3.400000                 NaN       NaN   
8     12.624198   52.220468  11.403157    Jerome H. Powell -1.350798   
9     18.466305   35.186261  16.205693     Stanley Fischer  0.522121   
10    -2.090000  121.220000  -3.400000                 NaN       NaN   
11    16.953460   36.246573  15.323457       Lael Brainard -0.217779   
12    -2.090000  121.220000  -3.400000                 NaN       NaN   
13    -2.090000  121.220000  -3.400000                 NaN       NaN   
14    17.066088   32.592551  16.108486     Stanley Fischer  0.642245   
15    -2.090000  121.220000  -3.400000                 NaN       NaN
```

I would like to first group the dataframe by 'Speaker' and then remove 'ARI', 'Flesch', and 'Kincaid' values that outliers as defined by being more than 3 standard deviations from the mean of the scores for the specific feature.

Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Can you put snippet of your data instead of attaching an image? It's easier for people to reproduce it.

Comment: Is that better? Thank you!

Comment: Perfect, thanks Graham. Someone will solve it soon hopefully :)

Comment: Explain the `NaN` in the `'Speaker'` column.  Do you want standard deviations specific to each `'Speaker'` or for the whole dataframe?  Do you want to remove rows in which all three columns are outliers?  Or if any of the three are outliers?

Comment: The NaN is 'Speaker' means that one speaker cannot be attributed to the data (it comes from an entire committee or organization). And I would like a standard deviation for each speaker, not the entire dataframe. I would not like to remove the row, but rather replace the outlier value with NaN. I'm obviously an entire noob, and thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the example data set?

Comment: Say the mean 'ARI' for 'Speaker' Janet Yellen is 2 with a standard deviation of 5. Then because 19.57 is more than 3 time the standard deviation away from the mean (2) the value would be filled with NaN. Ideally this process would be repeated for each column 'ARI', 'Flesch', and 'Kincaid' for each 'Speaker'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only required dependency for this approach is [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Suppose we have replaced the 'Speaker' columns values 'NaN' with something representative like 'CommitteOrganization'

`speaker = dataset['Speaker'].fillna(value='CommitteeOrganization')
dataset['Speaker'] = speaker`

So we have our data like:

```
Index ARI   Flesch  Kincaid Speaker Score
0   -2.090000   121.220000  -3.400000   CommitteeOrganization   NaN
1   8.276460    64.478573   9.034156    WilliamDudley   1.670275
2   19.570911   27.362067   17.253580   JanetYellen -0.604757
3   -2.090000   121.220000  -3.400000   CommitteeOrganization   NaN
4   -2.090000   121.220000  -3.400000   CommitteeOrganization   NaN
```

**Group by** with the *Pandas* function:

`datasetGrouped = dataset.groupby(by='Speaker').mean()`

So we have our data like:

```
Speaker             ARI Flesch  Kincaid Score
CommitteeOrganization   -2.090000   121.220000  -3.400000   NaN
JanetYellen 19.570911   27.362067   17.253580   -0.604757
JeromeH.Powell  12.624198   52.220468   11.403157   -1.350798
LaelBrainard    18.798471   26.657992   16.858818   -0.001191
StanleyFischer  17.766196   33.889406   16.157089   0.582183
WilliamDudley   8.276460    64.478573   9.034156    1.670275
```

Compute the Standard Deviations for each columns:

```
aristd = datasetGrouped['ARI'].std()
fleschstd = datasetGrouped['Flesch'].std()
kincaidstd = datasetGrouped['Kincaid'].std()
```

Replace the values with 'NaN' on the rows that meets the condition:

```
datasetGrouped.loc[abs(datasetGrouped.ARI) > aristd*3,'ARI'] = 'NaN'
datasetGrouped.loc[abs(datasetGrouped.Flesch) > fleschstd*3,'Flesch'] = 'NaN'
datasetGrouped.loc[abs(datasetGrouped.Kincaid) > kincaidstd*3,'Kincaid'] = 'NaN'
```

The final dataset is:

```
Speaker             ARI Flesch  Kincaid Score
CommitteeOrganization   -2.090000   NaN -3.400000   NaN
JanetYellen 19.570911   27.3621 17.253580   -0.604757
JeromeH.Powell  12.624198   52.2205 11.403157   -1.350798
LaelBrainard    18.798471   26.658  16.858818   -0.001191
StanleyFischer  17.766196   33.8894 16.157089   0.582183
WilliamDudley   8.276460    64.4786 9.034156    1.670275
```

Full code available on: [Github](https://github.com/alberduris/stackoverflow/blob/master/replacing_outliers_graham_streich/replacing_outlier_graham_streich.ipynb)

*Note: This could be done in less code than presented, but the answer it's done "step by step" for easy understanding.*

*Note2: Because the question was a little ambiguous, if I didn't understand well something and don't provide the right answer, don't hesitate to tell me and I'll update the answer if possible*

Comment: Thank you! One question I have is whether or not the standard deviations are calculated across all 'Speaker' types. Because individual speakers have multiple entries in the dataframe I would like to calculate a standard deviation and mean of ARI, Flesch, and Kincaid for each speaker and then replace outliers based on the standard deviation for that specific speaker. Does that make sense? Thanks again!

Comment: Individual speakers have multiple entries and the method used is mean `datasetGrouped = dataset.groupby(by='Speaker').mean()`

This is, the values for ARI, Flesch and Kincaid, in the grouped by Speaker dataset, are the mean of the individual ones for each 'Speaker'

Comment: Great, thank you -- I understand what's going on now!